# Windows Vista Backups?

Tags: windows, backup, windows-vista

I am trying to configure a Windows Backup on Vista but don't see some capabilities I would expect to be there.  For one, it looks like I can only select a Local Drive or a network share.  I want to use a local drive, but I want to use a sub folder of one of the drives.  Must I really pick the root?

As a work-around, I made a network share to the local drive, thinking I could then pick network share.  However, when I do this, I am prompted for credentials to hit the share, and none work.  However, the share works Explorer, and it works from other computers, so the access is configured correctly.

Is there any way to do what I am trying to do?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been a while since I used Vista, but I think if you select "Additional files" it will allow you to specify any folders you want after hitting "Next". First you must select the drive(s) you wish to back up. This backup makes shadow copies of your data, which I do not prefer myself, I always use 3rd party backup utilities that simply copies the data to another volume or network location

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was asking about the drive that I need to back up to, not which folders to grab, though.  So you believe you can only select a root drive?

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question.

Comment: I'm not talking about the "what files do you want to backup" step.  On the prior step the question is asked: "Where do you want to back up your files?"  It gives you the option of "Drive" or "Network".  My complaint is that I can't find a way to pick a sub folder of a drive.  It only allows for picking the root drive.

Comment: Ok,it is a limitation, It wants to create its own directory on the root of the drive for the backup data, I don't know of any way around it, sorry.